# Post-build event causing an exit code of 1

Tags: visual-studio, ilmerge, post-build-event

I have the following post-build event in my web application in Visual Studio.

> "..............\External\Tools\ILMerge\2.10.0\ILMerge"
>   /out:"$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Combined.dll"
>   "$(TargetPath)"
>   "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Utilities.dll"
>   "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)AjaxMin.dll"
>   "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll"
>   "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)EcmaScript.NET.modified.dll"

It's causing an exit code of 1. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Do you mean "exit code"?

Comment: Copy and paste what you see in the Output window.  Crappy job on posting the original bad command line btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/leveraging-ilmerge-to-simplify-deployment-and-your-users-experience/) might help you out